# Allow access to a website through my android app

Tags: android

So I just did a bit digging and found out that storing any type of passwords in any java application (in my case, android application) is not safe as the password can be retrieved by anyone by decompiling the java code. Now, on net, I, somewhere, also learned that a better way to interact with any database (my case), such as mysql, would be to create a web interface which by some way can differentiate between anyone else interacting without my app and someone interacting with web interface through my app. So, can someone tell me how to do so or if there is any better way to accomplish what I want to?

Answer (score 0):

for this you can check out firebase to interact with database and create your web application and mobile application based on that data . And there you can differentiate in them.

Answer (score 0):

One way which you already know is to create a web service layer which accesses your database.

Another way would be to use a BaaS to have a direct web layer access to a backend. There are many available BaaS solutions which would help you with this.

Third and best way in my opinion for new coders would be to use an existing auth service like Firebase Auth. This will pretty much give you all the features out of the box eg... signup emails,password resets, multiple login methods and their Firebase Auth UI will give you login screens without almost any code. Check it out, it actually is pretty good if it suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe chrome custom tabs are what you're looking for? They let you open an instance of chrome from within the app  https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs